# How can I send e-mails from python without having to enable less secure apps?

Tags: python, email, smtplib, feedback

I am having trouble sending an e-mail without having to enable google's less secure apps: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps . How can I modify the code in Python so that I can send e-mail without having to enable this? I need to disable this option, because I am building an application in which the user can send a feedback e-mail to the developer, so I cannot force the user to enable less secure apps.
My code in Python:

```
    def send_email(self):
        print("send e-mail to developer")
        sender_email = self.email.text
        sender_password = self.password.text
        sender_feedback = self.feedback_message.text
        print("email is: ", type(sender_email))
        print("pass is: ", sender_password)
        print("feedback message is: ", sender_feedback)

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()  # encrypt connection
        server.login(sender_email, sender_password)

        subject = 'Feedback'
        msg = sender_feedback

        msg = f"Subject: {subject} \n\n {msg}"
        server.sendmail(
            # from,to,message
            sender_email,
            'my_email@gmail.com',
            msg
        )
        print("E-MAIL HAS BEEN SENT!")
        server.quit()
```

Comment: Email is so broken by spammers that it's basically impossible to do right. You'll wrestle with spam filters, bounces, rejects, DKIM etc. I'd setup a simple HTTP form instead - sending a form from a program would be very simple. And your clients should not type their email password to your program anyway - you might get banned from GMail for doing this.

Comment: use oauth2 https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough

Comment: @Tometzky and how can I  work with a HTTP form from a desktop application? How do I know which user sent this form if they don't e-mail me?

Comment: Why does the web application need the users account credentials to send you an email?

Comment: @KlausD. how can the user send a feedback without having to enter their credentials? What other solution do you offer?

Comment: On how many (trustworthy) websites do you have to enter your email password to send a form via email to the website owner?

Comment: @KlausD. Ok, you are right. But i cannot find another option. How can I send the form by e-mail without the user having to enter the password?

Comment: Run your own mail server. Just for sending mails a simple qmail will do the job.

Comment: I would just put a notice in the app saying 'Send feedback to "feedback@mycompany.com"'.  It will almost certainly be more convenient for the user to use their mail client rather than whatever form you come up with, and you won't have to write or maintain the email code.

Comment: @snakecharmerb well, i want to create a form where user enters a message and his/her e-mail and just send the feedback message to my e-mail without them having to open another page to write the e-mail. I think this way it's simpler, but I don't know how to send the feedback without user's e-mail password...

Answer (score 0):

According to [POP3/SMTP compatible with 2 factor authentication? - Help - Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUcWx-YpjoeXc), you need to [set up an "app password"](https://support.teamgate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002064229-How-to-create-a-password-to-connect-email-while-using-2-step-verification-in-Gmail-) to be used instead of your regular password to be able to use an SMTP client when "2-step verification" is turned on for your Google account.

Comment: Yes, but i cannot force the users to set up a new password. I want the feedback to happen more rapidly, i think that setting a second password will make users change their mind regarding sending the feedback...